# "ld: library not found" error when trying to compile against a shared object

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to build a dummy example where some source code uses a library dynamically linked. For this I have the following project structure:

First, I have a "dependency" **module** that I'm trying to use as a common extraction of code that should be in its own file and, when the shared object is created, should be included with the library.

```cpp
// dependency.h

int get_number();
```

```cpp
// dependency.cpp
#include "dependency.h"


int get_number()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Of course, I have a **library** "libnum" that contains the function that has to be run by the main code.

```cpp
// libnum.h

int get_the_library_number();
```

```cpp
// libnum.cpp

#include "dependency.h"

int get_the_library_number()
{
    return get_number() + 5;
}
```

And finally I have the "main" **code** of the project:

```cpp
#include "libnum.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << get_the_library_number() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** All of these files are placed in the same directory.

However, I'm struggling to get this all to work and to obtain an executable `./main` file.

Learning from other Stack Overflow questions, I'm assuming that this is what I should be doing:

1. First we create an object file for the library:

   ```
   g++ -c libnum.cpp
   ```
2. We now create a shared object from the output of the previous command (libnum.o). Because we have a dependency, we need to tell the compiler where the source code is located:

   ```
   g++ -shared libnum.o dependency.cpp -o libnum.so
   ```
3. Finally, we compile main.cpp explicitly telling the linker where the library is located and its name. We do this by using the `-L` flag with the directory where it should look for the .so file (the current directory) and the `-l` flag with the name of the `.so` file **without the lib** prefix:

   ```
   g++ main.cpp -L. -lnum
   ```

I'm stuck in this step. The linker returns the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lnum
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: And your proof that `libnum.so` actually exists, in the current directory?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just added the missing `-o libnum.so` to the post, sorry!

Comment: Is that the full linker output? It isn't saying its ignoring your library for some reason? I presume this in on Linux?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, it is the full output of `g++ main.cpp -L. -lnum`. This is being run in macOS.

Comment: If you are on mac why are you creating `.so` files? Probably why GCC can't find your library

Comment: I'm actually testing some code that I'm going to deploy on a Raspberry Pi. Care to explain why I can't create .so files in macOS? I'm kind of new with all of this.

Comment: mac uses `.dylib`, you can call your libraries whatever you like but the linker wont find them automatically if they don't match the target platforms naming scheme

Comment: Well, you were right. I tried the code in the Raspberry Pi that runs Linux and it all worked corectly. Thank you very much @AlanBirtles!